# Update Googlesheet based on the the number and value of cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to google scripts and have been working on a script that is attached to a google sheet that needs to update and assign accounts to requester based on the information that they submit in a google form.

The script is supposed to work like this: Once a user submits the form with the information regarding which grade level, features type and number of accounts they want, the script is supposed to search through the rows of the sheet named "Production" to find the row(s) that match the grade level and whether the account has the two specific features turned on or off and assign those accounts to the requester.

While I am able to get the relevant information once the form submits, I am having trouble with updating the sheet correctly. When I run the code it updates the first row of the sheet and doesn't utilize the if statement at all. Can someone help to point me in the right direction as to what I am doing incorrectly?

I have also include a link to the google sheet below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mPTIpWYc7KEmx-YPa9RPe2VDdHhBcvyLw9TapLdq_qQ/edit?usp=sharing

```html
    
function assignAccounts(){ 
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var responseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LS Demo Request Responses");
  var lastRow = responseSheet.getLastRow()
  var LSrequester = ss.getRange('C'+lastRow).getValue();
  var demoUser = ss.getRange('D'+lastRow).getValue(); 
  var demoUserAffliation = ss.getRange('E'+lastRow).getValue();
  var hasPowerText = ss.getRange('O'+lastRow).getValue();
  var hasPC = ss.getRange('N'+lastRow).getValue();
  var numStudentAccounts = ss.getRange('P'+lastRow).getValue();
  var numTeacherAccounts = ss.getRange('Q'+lastRow).getValue();
  var requestedGrade = ss.getRange('M'+lastRow).getValue();
  var requestDate = ss.getRange('A'+lastRow).getValue();
  var expirationDate = ss.getRange('R'+lastRow).getValue();
  
   
  
  
//get data from sheet containing demo accounts
  var myspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var productionSheet = myspreadsheet.getSheetByName("Accounts");
  var range = productionSheet.getRange("A2");
  var currentRow = range.getRow();
  var numRow = currentRow;

  
  
  var classCol = productionSheet.getRange('F' + numRow).getValue();
  var studentCol = productionSheet.getRange('I' + numRow).getValue();
  var teacherCol = productionSheet.getRange('G'  + numRow).getValue();
  var studentPasswordCol = productionSheet.getRange('J'  + numRow).getValue();
  var teacherPasswordCol = productionSheet.getRange('H'  + numRow).getValue();
  var pcStatusCol = productionSheet.getRange('K'  + numRow).getValue();
  var ptmStatusCol = productionSheet.getRange('L' + numRow).getValue();
  var gradeLevelCol = productionSheet.getRange('E'  + numRow).getValue();
  var isEmptyCheck = productionSheet.getRange('A' + numRow).getValue();
  
  
//set the number of rows that must be allotted for the demo account creation   
  if (numStudentAccounts >= numTeacherAccounts){ 
    var num = numStudentAccounts;
    Logger.log("num is equal to student accounts");
 }else {
    var num = numTeacherAccounts; 
    Logger.log("num is equal to teacher accounts");
  }
  
  
  

//Update the 'Production: The New LightSail School' tab with data from the response form (replace data in the spreadsheet)
// Once row meets crieria select specific cells to update request and expiration dates, Sales Owner, Org of requestor,     
  var productionData = productionSheet.getDataRange();
  var productionNumRows = productionData.getNumRows();
  var productionRowValues = productionData.getValues();
  var productionNumCol = productionData.getNumColumns();
  var i = 1;
  var j = 0;


  for(var i = 1; i < productionNumRows; i++){
    if ((pcStatusCol === hasPC &&  ptmStatusCol === hasPowerText  && gradeLevelCol === requestedGrade)  && isEmptyCheck === null  && j < num)
      productionSheet.getRange('A'+numRow).setValue(LSrequester); // sales owner
      productionSheet.getRange('B'+numRow).setValue(requestDate); //start date
      productionSheet.getRange('C'+numRow).setValue(expirationDate); // expiration dates
      productionSheet.getRange('D'+numRow).setValue(demoUserAffliation); // org name
      j+1
      Logger.log("data found");
     }
    }
```

Comment: No use of spreadsheet link if you don't make it public

Comment: @Ritz I've updated the link.